# quick question about translating 'It would rain on our wedding day.'

Tags: meaning

I know that this sentence falls under the 'ironic / typical behavior' category, since you could add 'wouldn't it?' at the end of it. It's just that in an English-Persian dictionary, the author has used the Persian word for 'definitely' in the translation of this sentence. Is that for the irony? Is that OK?

Comment: What language is the original sentence in? Is what you have quoted in the thread title the original or a translation? How did the English word "definitely" pop up in the translation of an English sentence to another language?

Comment: Hi Jack. The original sentence is in English, the one in the title of this thread. I'm talking about an English-Persian dictionary. And the translation includes the Persian word for "definitely". I'm so sorry I wasn't clear.

Comment: If it were being used in a sarcastic sense, the actual words would be the same, but there would be emphasis on the conditional, well as the overall sentence: *It **would** rain on our wedding day!* Without any emphasis at all, the *would* is more commonly interpreted as expressing a simple statement of fact rather than irony: *(Two years ago, when we were married, we didn't know) it would rain on our wedding day.*

Comment: Thank you very much for your useful comment, Jason.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is, I believe, an example of definition B2 of *would* according to [Cambridge Dictionaries](https://dictionary.cambridge.org/us/dictionary/english/would) website,

> used to suggest that what happens is expected because it is typical, especially of a person's behavior

The implication is that something unpleasant is expected or unavoidable because of the nature of things (or of a person).  It is always spoken with a strong emphasis on the word *would*. I associate this with British rather than American usage, but it could be more common in America than I'm aware of.

Or at any rate, the translator of your English-Persian dictionary has treated the sentence that way.

Comment: Aha, now I fully understand. Thanks a lot!